# Low mob spawn rates (ilMango dispenserless mob farm)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-realms

Me and my friend have recently built ilmango his [mob farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg17wAr_IOI).
Now I have tested this mob farm in my single player world and it spawned a ton of mobs as promised. Now the thing is we built this mob farm on a **Realm**.
I started thinking it maybe had to do something with the fact it is on a **Realm?** We used the exact same dimensions as ilmango and we have the same **y levels** etc.

So yeah, we play on a Minecraft realm.

Version: 1.14.3

The difficulty is set to Normal, maybe this has something to do with the rates aswell?

[image: Image of the mob farm]

This is a staircase we built of glass, that we built to the afk spot as seen in il mango his video.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be related to the [render distance bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-2536), or it could be a [separate Realms-related issue](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-2536).

Whichever of those issues are at the root, the result is that **traditional mob farms which rely on natural spawning do not work on Realms servers**.

Here are some accounts of other people having the same problem: [1](https://www.reddit.com/r/realms/comments/3qabde/troubleshooting_problems_with_mob_grinders_on/) [2](https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/servers-java-edition/minecraft-realms/2131188-realms-mob-farm-problem) [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/2hjsqf/realms_mob_spawn_rules_on_realms_vs_nonrealms/)

Comment: From what I have heard about the render distance bug it is with 10 or lower, I have my render distance set to 16. About the realms related issue I read somewhere that the realm jar files are the same as normal servers. Thanks for sharing this, it is not that big of a deal that there are not that many of mobs spawning as seen in ilmango his video but it would be cool to see ;p